# PostgreSQL Query for Non Alphanumeric

Tags: postgresql-9.2, pgadmin, opensuse

I have been searching Stackoverflow for queries on how to find cells that have special characters.

I saw this on another post

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

and patterend my code from it below

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM ITEM WHERE DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9 .-]%'
```

But it is not working for me with the below result showing '-' and '.' and whitespace.

"2016 LANCER EX GT-A 2.0G CVT"

"2016 MIRAGE GLX 1.2G MT"

"2016 MIRAGE G4 GLX 1.2G MT (UPG)"

"2016 MIRAGE G4 GLX 1.2G CVT (UPG)"

I tried changing it to

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM ITEM WHERE DESCRIPTION ~* '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%'
```

which returns 0 results.

Any help is appreciated. I am confused why it works for other people and not mine.
I am using Postgresql and PGadmin on an Opensuse OS.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe that Postgres `LIKE` supports regex such as the following:

```
WHERE DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9 .-]%'
```

But you can instead use the tilde operator to access full regex.
Expressed verbally, I think the logic you want here is:

> Find any string which does *not* have one or more *non* alphanumeric characters present in the string.

Use a regex pattern with the right pattern which covers the entire string:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION
FROM ITEM
WHERE DESCRIPTION ~ '^.*[^A-Za-z0-9 .-].*$'
```

This would match any description having one or more characters which are *not* letters, numbers, space, dot or dash.

Comment: I think you mean `WHERE DESCRIPTION ~` and not `WHERE DESCRIPTION !~`

Comment: I agree with your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres can handle regex but it uses the keywords `SIMILAR TO` and `NOT SIMILAR TO` [seen here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-matching.html).

I think what you want is 
`SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM ITEM WHERE DESCRIPTION NOT SIMILAR TO '%[a-zA-Z0-9 .-]%'`